# Exclude the row which has numeric characters, only at the beginning of the row

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a similar table as below:

```
product      
01 apple
02 orange
banana 10
```

I am trying to exclude only rows which start with a number. If the number is not in the beginning then it should not be excluded. The desired table output should be like this:

```
product      
banana 10
```

However with my current query, it excludes everything as soon as there is a number in the row:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE product NOT LIKE '%0%'
```

Could anyone please suggest me on how to tackle this? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE left(product, 1) NOT IN ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')
```

Comment: Nice - avoids regex.

Comment: Actually, taking this approach, we can maybe do a bit better.  I recall there is a function to get the ASCII value of a character.  Take the first character from the string, get the ASCII value, and then compare it to the ASCII range for '0' to '9'.  That will save you needing the little hash join to perform the NOT IN.

Answer (score 2):

regex to match lines that don't start with number is

```
^[^0-9].*
```

An sql query in mysql would look like

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE product RLIKE '^[^0-9].*'
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggested solution however with my dmbs, it does not recognize RLIKE.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend regular expressions.  In Redshift, this looks like:

```
where product ~ '^[^0-9]'
```

I might also suggest:

```
where left(product, 1) not between '0' and '9'
```